# How to get all XML nodes with XPath in PHP that contain a certain child node

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to find a way on how to properly use xpath to select certain elements and my solution partially works and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is a sample xml:

```
<Database>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <Name>A</Name>
            <Locations>
                <Location>A</Location>
                <Location>B</Location>
                <Location>C</Location>
            </Locations>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Name>B</Name>
            <Locations>
                <Location>E</Location>
            </Locations>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <Name>C</Name>
            <Locations>
                <Location>D</Location>
                <Location>E</Location>
            </Locations>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Database>
```

And I'm using this php code to get all Items that contain a Location "E"

```
$LocationFilter = "E" //hard written, it's actually a GET param
$filter = $xml->xpath("//Items/Item[contains(Locations/Location,'".$LocationFilter."')]");

foreach ($filter as $Item) {
    echo($filter->Name);
}
```

and instead of getting BC (names of the items), I only get B, or in other words, I only get those items whose first location is E, and not all those who contains E on any position.

I'm not really sure why this doesn't work, but I do hope I've explained it well enough.

Answer (score 2):

`contains()` expects singleton to be passed as the first parameter. In case of multiple nodes received, only the first will be evaluated. This explains why the XPath didn't return `Item` with name `C` in your test.

In the situation where you have to use `contains()`, the correct way would be to apply the method on individual `Location` element :

```
//Items/Item[Locations/Location[contains(.,'E')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

changing this

```
$filter = $xml->xpath("//Items/Item[contains(Locations/Location,'".$LocationFilter."')]");
```

into this

```
$filter = $xml->xpath("//Items/Item[Locations/Location = '".$LocationFilter."'] ");
```

fixed the issue and items are now showing properly.